# fetching records from multiple tables using ado.net and mapping them to Business objects C#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Here si
One Printer Can have multiple PriterTrays and PaperSizes,Schema is given below.

Table Schema :  3 Tables
1)Printer:
PrinterId,Name,PrinterStatus
1,ABC,2

2)PrinterTray
PrinterTrayId,Name,PrinterID
100,xyz,1
101,ddy,1

2)PaperSizes
paperSizeId,Name,PrinterId
1,abc,1
2,dww,1

BusinessObject/Model : (it will have complete information of printer along with respective printerTrays and printerSizes,as shown below)

class  => Printer

printerid,
Name,
printerStatus,
list of PaperTrays;
list of paperSizes;

I want to fetch the records from Printer table and also dump the values of associated tables(PrinterTrays and Papersizes) using ado.net(Datatable,Dataset etc Not entity Framework).So that i can Map them with Business Object.

Thanks

Comment: what is your question? or are you making some sort of request here?..

Comment: I want sample code.or any idea regarding how to Fetch data from Printer(first Table) along with other associated tables(PrinterTrays and PaperSizes). and pass/mapp them to Business Objects.Hope you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue three separate `SqlCommand`s and compose the results. You can also issue one `SqlCommand` with three distinct `SELECT` statements that returns three result sets (Printer, Tray, Paper). You then read multiple results sets using [IDataReader.NextResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx).